# YT Data API throws Error 403 for just one video

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I was using the YouTube Data API v3 to put the current view count in my video title just like in this video ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxV14h0kFs0 ) and it works!

I set it up in pythonanywhere for this video ID: 7vSw7XRivWY, worked like a charm, still running.
Then I tried to do the same thing for another video (ID: fDh-qcbIxtU ) and now it throws

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&alt=json returned "The request metadata is invalid.">

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

this error. I'm using the exact same code I used for the other ID, all I did was changing my variable for the video ID to the other one.

I've no clue why this happens. I retried it multiple times, I tried it with different API scopes, I tried it with another API client key - same result, not working.

In my python code I implemented a method change_title that takes the apiclient and the video ID as parameters then first fetches the view count & snippet part ( which contains the title ), edits the title section of the snippet, and then updates the video accordingly.

As already stated, it works for any other of my videos but not for this one (ID: fDh-qcbIxtU). I'm 100% sure I put in the correct ID and that I didn't change anything else.

Here's the whole file that is being executed:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.channels.list
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

import time

scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']


def like_video(youtube, videoID):
    youtube.videos().rate(
        id=videoID,
        rating='like'
    ).execute()


def change_title(youtube, videoID):
    video_list_response_statistics = youtube.videos().list(
        id=videoID,
        part="statistics"
    ).execute()

    videos_list_statistics = video_list_response_statistics['items'][0]['statistics']

    views = videos_list_statistics['viewCount']
    print("Views: " + str(views))

    snippetPart = youtube.videos().list(
        id=videoID,
        part="snippet"
    ).execute()

    # Since the request specified a video ID, the response only contains one
    # video resource. This code extracts the snippet from that resource.
    videos_list_snippet = snippetPart['items'][0]['snippet']
    print(videos_list_snippet)
    videos_list_snippet['title'] += " [" + str(views) + " Views]"

    videos_update_response = youtube.videos().update(
        part='snippet',
        body=dict(
            id=videoID,
            snippet=videos_list_snippet
        )).execute()


def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.

    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "0"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "credentials.json"

    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    i = 1

    videoID = "fDh-qcbIxtU"
    while True:
        print("Update No" + str(i))
        response = change_title(youtube, videoID)
        print(response)
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1000)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks for anyone that's taking the time to try & solve my issue.

Comment: Can you share the relevant code? I'm not sure how much we can do otherwise.

Comment: sure, just give me a second to find the option to edit the questioon

Comment: Added the code. The credentials.json contains the client secret & id & such and is 100% guaranteed to be correct because it's working perfectly fine with other video IDs. Thanks for taking the time to try & solve my issue!

Comment: I find it strange that its asking for an api key when you are using oauth2 with an installed application.

Comment: @DalmTo I'm not sure if I understood it correctly but I think the client id + secret is what identifies the requests as coming from my project. But when I run the program it first asks me to login, accept that I grant the program certain rights (manage yt account) and then I get a long code of random chars which I need to insert into the program before it continues.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error for my one particular youtube channel, and that was because it was managed by a brand account than its owner account.

It might not be helpful in your case but maybe it can help others facing this issue.

Just authorize with the right account.